# QT, GDCM lib problems. "Undefined reference to '_imp_ZNgdcmr11ImageReader...'

Tags: c++, qt, gdcm

I want to run GDCM lib (v.3.0.0) using C ++ in the API QT 5.13.1 (MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit) to read DICOM files. This is normal when I include the header files and see all the methods in the libraries. But here
ascending error when I try to run:

> undefined reference to '_imp__ZN4gdcm11ImageReaderC1Ev'

Here is what i'am already tried:

1. include all GDCM libs
2. downgrade gpp

*dcm_reader.pro file*

```
...
INLCUDEPATH += -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDCM 3.0\include\gdcm-3.0'
LIBS        += -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDCM 3.0\bin'
LIBS        += -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDCM 3.0\lib'
LIBS        += -lgdcmcharls -lgdcmCommon -lgdcmDICT -lgdcmDSED -lgdcmexpat -lgdcmIOD -lgdcmjpeg8 -lgdcmjpeg12 -lgdcmjpeg16 -lgdcmMEXD -lgdcmMSFF -lgdcmuuid -lgdcmzlib -lsocketxx

#LIBS += -lgdcmImageReader // Raised error "cannot find -lgdcmImageReader"
```

*main.cpp*

```
incude <gdcmImageReader.h>

int main()
{
    gdcm::ImageReader reader; // Error: undefined reference to '_imp__ZN4gdcm11ImageReaderC1Ev'
}
```

I have suspicions that this error is due to the fact that I do not to have the full version of the libs or that the GDCM librs is not suitable for the QT compliants.

Compile output:

```
18:15:25: Запускаются этапы для проекта dcm_reader... 18:15:25: Запускается: "C:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean -j4 C:/Qt/Qt5.13.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug clean C:/Qt/Qt5.13.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/mingw32-make
-f Makefile.Release clean mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug' del debug\moc_predefs.h mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug' del release\moc_predefs.h Н• г§ •вбп ≠ ©в® C:\Users\user\Documents\build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\debug\moc_predefs.h Н• г§ •вбп ≠ ©в® C:\Users\user\Documents\build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\release\moc_predefs.h del debug\main.o del release\main.o Н• г§ •вбп ≠ ©в® C:\Users\user\Documents\build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\release\main.o mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug' mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug' 18:15:27: ѕроцесс ЂC:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exeї завершился успешно. 18:15:27: «апускаетс€: ЂC:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\bin\qmake.exeї C:\Users\user\Documents\dcm_reader\dcm_reader.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" 18:15:28: ѕроцесс ЂC:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\bin\qmake.exeї завершился успешно. 18:15:28: «апускаетс€: ЂC:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exeї -f C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug/Makefile qmake_all mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'. 18:15:28: ѕроцесс ЂC:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exeї завершился успешно. 18:15:28: Запускается: "C:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j4 C:/Qt/Qt5.13.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug' g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -Wextra
-fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\dcm_reader -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\libs\GDCM_3.0\include\gdcm-3.0 -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\dcm_reader\main.cpp g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console
-mthreads -o debug\dcm_reader.exe debug/main.o  -LC:\Qt\libs\GDCM_3.0\bin -LC:\Qt\libs\GDCM_3.0\lib -lgdcmcharls -lgdcmCommon -lgdcmDICT -lgdcmDSED -lgdcmexpat -lgdcmgetopt -lgdcmIOD -lgdcmjpeg8 -lgdcmjpeg12 -lgdcmjpeg16 -lgdcmmd5 -lgdcmMEXD -lgdcmMSFF -lgdcmzlib C:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\lib\libQt5Cored.a    debug/main.o: In function `main': C:\Users\user\Documents\build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug/../dcm_reader/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4gdcm11ImageReaderC1Ev' C:\Users\user\Documents\build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug/../dcm_reader/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4gdcm11ImageReaderD1Ev' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:65: debug/dcm_reader.exe] Error 1 mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:38: debug] Error 2 mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/build-dcm_reader-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug' 18:15:31: ѕроцесс ЂC:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exeї завершился с кодом 2. Ошибка при сборке/разворачивании проекта dcm_reader (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.13.1 MinGW 32-bit) Во время выполнения этапа "Сборка" 18:15:31: ѕрошло времени: 00:05.
```

Comment: What is the compile output for your build?

Comment: From what I could see, gdcmMSFF should contain this symbol. Where did you get GDCM 3.0 from? Are you sure it was compiled with g++ instead of MSVC? Are you not mixing 32-bit and 64-bit libraries? Does `nm` tell you this symbol is present in `gdcmMSFF.lib`?

Comment: @hyde added to the question

Comment: @Botje
1) I took GDCM from here https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/releases
2) Not sure. How to check it?
3) No mixing

Comment: The windows binaries are not correct for `mingw`. You will have to build it yourself. Thankfully this is easy to do with `CMake`  and `mingw`.

Comment: I will try, @drescherjm

Comment: @drescherjm, hey listen: 1) I downloaded the gdcm source code and after that 2) I used the command 'cmake [link to source code] -G "MinGW Makefile"'. After assembly, I do not see .h or .dll files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to build after that or is that what you meant by assembly?

Comment: Could NOT find LibXslt

Cannot build man page from docbook

Could NOT find DCMTK

Comment: @drescherjm, yeap, after build

Comment: here is only .a files in bin folder